# Combining and Permuting items of two different arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do I return all possible combinations [12345], [12354] up to [54312], [54321] without having to run 120 for...loop as in the case of combining a 2-item array in the code below?

To return all possible combinations from the given array $word = [1,2],

```
//break the array into 2 separate arrays
$arr1 = $word[0]; $arr2 = $word[1];

//computer for first array item...each item will have 2 loops
for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){
for($j=0; $j<count($arr2); $j++){
$ret = $arr1[$i] . $arr2[$j]; array_push($result, $ret);
}
}

//computer for second array item..each item will have 2 loops
for($i=0; $i<count($arr2); $i++){
for($j=0; $j<count($arr1); $j++){
$ret = $arr2[$i] . $arr1[$j]; array_push($result, $ret);
}
}
//display the result

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
echo result([$i];
}
```

The above code works well.

But for a 5-item array [1,2,3,4,5], it will require about (5 items * 24 loops) = 120 loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen, you wanted to split `2 strings into chars` and obtain all combination by `2 chars`: first form `blank1` and second from `blank2`.
Instead of doing the combination manually use a regular `for-loop`.

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($blank1); $i++)
{
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($blank2); $j++)
  {
     //set combination
     $aux = $blank1[$i].$blank2[$j];
     array_push($result, $aux);
  }

}
//result should be populated with combination of 2
//just list it and use as need
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{
   echo $result[$i];
}
//same with stored or checking on db : use loops
```

For multiple combination, use more nested loops 
eg: `[blank1][blank2][blank1]` - 3 combination

```
$result = array();
//1
for ($i = 0; $i < count($blank1); $i++)
{
  //2
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($blank2); $j++)
  {
     //3
     for ($k = 0; $k < count($blank1); $k++)
     {
     //set combination
     $aux = $blank1[$i].$blank2[$j].$blank1[$k];
     array_push($result, $aux);
     }
   }

}
```

Same as any number you wanted ! It will be a little annoying if have to write many loops but note `while can be used with an adequate algorithm`. But for the moment just keep as simple as you can and get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a simpler way..but it takes a lot of time to load...unlike the manual way. Thank you very much.

Comment: Time should be the same (same number of combination ...) but less to write ! One enhancement could be to get rid of `$aux` and add the calculation directly (but as time save it's not visible for user ... is saving memory and time by avoiding unnecessary storing_vars ... means time for small sets up to hundred can be resumed in less the 1s). Have fun with coding !

Comment: How do I adopt this combination for 3, 4, 5...n combinations?

Comment: I understand that your code works with the initial 2-array lists.. but I am looking at a single array, containing more than 2, 3...n elements.... Only one variable $wordArray = ['a','b','c','d'...'n']

Comment: same thing, use as many loops as combination and just modify the result `$aux = $blank1[$i].$blank1[$j].$blank1[$k]...$blank1[$numberOfCombination]`. More over after spliting depends on condition could have more chars into 1_itemToCombine. Eg=`ab#cde#efgh`.Split by `#` and return array on [0] will have a `string_ab` and not a `char` ...

Comment: That is, in nCr, where n is 3 and r is 5, the total combination will be 20 different results...eg: [A,B,C,D,E] by 3 combinations will be (ABC, ABD, ABE, ABE, BAC, BAD, BAE, BCA, BCD, BCE, BDA, BDC, BDE, ACB, ACD, ACE, BEA, BEC, BED) etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211873/discussion-between-cybernetiquettes-and-traian-geicu).

Comment: The code is not doing math combination `(C[n,k] or sets A[n,k)`, So into my code [AAA],[AAB], [BBB] is valid. If want math combination just add the condition `if`. Eg: `not[AAA]` means `$w[$i] != $w[$j] or $w[$i] != $w[$k] or $w[$j] != $w[$k]`. Now `[AAD] [ADA] [ADD] [AAA]` is not added on `result_array`